# Suspend options with KDM greeter

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, power-management, suspend, kdm

I am not able to suspend my desktop to RAM from the KDM greeter. I am able to suspend it to RAM when logged into KDE using the sleep option from the logout menu and by pressing the sleep key on my keyboard. When I am logout out and sitting at the KDM greeter login screen there is no sleep option in the shutdown menu and the sleep key on my keyboard does nothing. If I switch over to a TTY, the sleep key still does nothing (technically it types an @ for some reason). I would like a way of suspending my desktop to RAM while not logged in. On my laptop, there is no option to sleep in the shutdown menu of the KDM greeter login screen, but if I close the lid or use the sleep key (fn+f4) the computer suspends to RAM. On my laptop, the sleep key works at both the KDM greeter and on a TTY.

Is there a way of adding a sleep option to KDM greeter shutdown menu?
How do I enable the sleep key to work on my desktop while at a TTY and the KDM greeter?